# Fix "Missing SOAP Operations in Project" error in SoapUI

Tags: web-services, testing, soap, project, soapui

I'm using SoapUI 4.5.1 and unable to add a TestRequest under TestStep. When I try to add a TestRequest, I'm getting the following error dialog.

```
               "Missing SOAP Operations in Project"
```

Can anyone please tell me how can I solve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

This is problem with your wsdl try to add your wsdl once again and create your project from begining.